# Ruby & Mongoid - Uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm getting "uninitialized constant SwimResult":

```
class LegResult
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :secs, type: Float
  embedded_in :entrant
  embeds_one :event, as: :parent
  validates_presence_of :event

  after_initialize do |doc|
    doc.calc_ave
  end


  def calc_ave

  end

  def secs=value  
    self[:secs] = value
    calc_ave

  end
end


class SwimResult < LegResult
  field :pace_100,  as: :pace_100, type: Float

  def calc_ave
  end
end



class BikeResult < LegResult
  field :mph,  as: :mph, type: Float

  def calc_ave
  end
end
```

I know it can occur when classes are in a separate files, but in my case they're all in one - class LegResult and two subclasses inheriting after it. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Each of your classes should be its own file, named after the class, eg. `app/models/swim_result.rb`. This way the Rails autoloading mechanism will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you need to move SwimResult and class BikeResult to swim_result.rb and bike_result.rb 
Make sure to require 'leg_result' before using ,This would ensure that the files are loaded in proper order